# python float to str strange

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have a very strange problem in python.
I tried running the following code in the console：

```
>>> str(23438.67709815)
'23438.6770982'
>>> str(22222.67709815)
'22222.6770982'
>>> str(11111.67709815)
'11111.6770981'
```

The last number is strange; when should it be carried, and another not?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the linked question, because that would require the OP to know that the issue is caused by floats' representations of numbers.

Comment: Hmm, it has something to do with 16384 (0x4000)...

Comment: `>>> '%.20f' % 22222.67709815`
`'22222.67709815000125672668'`
`>>> '%.20f' % 11111.67709815`
`'11111.67709814999943773728'`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I know that the cause is float representation. But OP might not. Hence, just linking her/him to a question on float representation might not help. (I mean, apart from me mentioning it just now.)